# ansible loop on different device names to run tasks in block based on result of other global tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,
I have a situation where I want to run a block of tasks only if two tasks outside the block conditions are met, which I specified under block `WHEN`. but am getting error, any hint? it is failing on the first task itself of `apt-install parted`

I want tasks to run for each device listed in my values file so am using loop. hope it is correct?

values.yml

```
local_volume_mount_disks:
  - device: /dev/nvme2n1
    partitions:

  - device: /dev/nvme1n1
    partitions:

  - device: /dev/sdd
    partitions:
```

task

```
 - name: Check device existence on node
  shell: "lsblk -p -l | grep {{ item.0.device }}"
  loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
  register: device_exists
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Check if device is mounted on ROOT /
  shell: lsblk -l -p | grep -w "{{ item.0.device }}" | grep -w /
  loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
  register: is_device_root
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: local_volume_mount partition format and mount devices
  block:
  - name: apt-install parted
    apt:
      name: parted=3.2*
      update_cache: yes

  when:
    - local_volume_mount_enabled|bool
    - device_exists.rc == 0
    - is_device_root.rc != 0
```

output

```
 TASK [local_volume_mount : Check device existence on node] *********************
....postgres'}])

 
TASK [local_volume_mount : Check if device is mounted on ROOT /] ***************
Thursday 15 April 2021  00:20:58 +0000 (0:00:05.007)       0:00:05.148 ******** 

"stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
  ...ignoring
```

```
  TASK [local_volume_mount : apt-install parted] *********************************
   Thursday 15 April 2021  00:21:02 +0000 (0:00:03.476)       0:00:08.625 ******** 
   fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'device_exists.rc == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (device_exists.rc == 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/team/run_ansible_playbook/k8s/baremetal/roles/local_volume_mount/tasks/main.yml': line 18, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  block:\n  - name: apt-install parted\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: There is a lot to say on your above example. I'll just focus on two points to try to put you on track: 1) [registering with a look creates a `result` list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop). This is why you get an undefined var error. 2) Your shell tasks are getting info already available in [ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)

Comment: Please reduce the question size as much as possible in order to get an answer.

Comment: okay, I reduced it. can anyone propose one solution? I want to run a block based on two conditions from two tasks outside block

Comment: Your question still contains the same basic issue regarding the use of your registered var from a loop (read the above link). Simply debug the content of `device_exists` and it will become clear that `device_exists.rc` is not defined, but `device_exists.results[0].rc`, `device_exists.results[1].rc`, .... are defined. Now what is the exact condition you want to test?

Comment: You should also debug `ansible_devices` and `ansible_mounts` and study their content. You will probably find the info you're looking for is already there. (`gather_facts` must not be false for those to exist).

Comment: Basically, I want to run the block on each of `device_exists.results[x].rc` where x is number that depends on my device names in `values.yml` so, my intent is every device should be checked if it `exists` and if it is not mounted to `/` and if both satisfied, i want block to be executed else skipped.